# iOS simulator screen size not equal to window size

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-simulator

I have a strange issue with my iOS simulator. It does not fit my Simulator Windows size. This is not a real problem, but the thing is that I cannot make screenshots anymore, when I save a screenshot, it saves the entire simulator window, not only the iOS screen.

How can I fix this problem?

The strange thing is that was working a few hours ago, even if the iOS screen was smaller, when I saved a screenshot, it saved at full resolution.

I will attack an image of the simulator Window. Window scale is 100%. If I change it, also the iOS inside will change too, but never goes full screen.

[image: iOS simulator]

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Saw this sollution. Try it:  For me pressing command + 2 or command + 3 when the ios simulator opens up solve the problem. Pressing the above keys do scaled down the simulator size.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Xcode

Comment: @ChrisM. Please update this question with how you solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Now It's more flexible with Xcode 9- Simulator. You can pick & drag any corner of simulator to resize it and set it according to your requirement.

Look at this snapshot:

[image]

**Note: With Xcode 9.1, Simulator scale options are changed.**

There are several other ways also, to scale your simulator.

**Keyboard short-keys**:

 According to Xcode 9.1

```
Physical Size       ⌘ 1      command + 1
Pixel Accurate      ⌘ 2      command + 2
```

According to Xcode 9

```
50% Scale           ⌘ 1      command + 1
100% Scale          ⌘ 2      command + 2
200% Scale          ⌘ 3      command + 3
```

**Simulator scale options Menu**:

*Xcode 9.1*

> Menubar  >>  Window  >>  "Here available options for simulator scaling" (Physical Size & Pixel Accurate)

[image]

*Xcode 9.0*

> Menubar  >>  Window  >>  Scale  >>  "Here available options for simulator scaling"

[image]

**Using Terminal Command**

Follow these steps to scale simulator using terminal commands

1. Close/Quit simulator. (if open)
2. Open `Terminal` app (using Spotlight search, Press `⌘ + SPACE` to open spotlight search)
3. Copy following text and paste it next to terminal cursor.

`defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale "0.3"`

4. Open 'Simulator' (Run your iOS project using Xcode).

You will find simulator scale update.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the simulator scale to 100% (which you can do using the keyboard shortcut cmd-1), you can take a screenshot with full resolution in Simulator by pressing cmd-S. This works even for simulated devices that do not fit on your Mac's screen in full scale (like the iPad Pro).  You'll still get the full window including the part that is not visible on the screen.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in Xcode 10.3.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have chosen a "resizable" iPhone or iPad. Go to "Hardware" under the menu bar and select another device. You can also press ⌘ + 2 for 75% size or ⌘ + 3 for 50% size.

Comment: No, is not resizable. iPhone 6 Plus is in the attached screenshot